# QDockWidget visible separator

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I have a left docked `QDockWidget` in my application. I want it to have visible borders and separators but it does not have by default.

How can I setup a dock widget so that it has visible edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always have a framed widget as a child of the dock widget, however then you will have dual frames when floating the widget.

Comment: It turns out that I have been using a style in main.cpp. After I removed the line QApplication::setStyle(new QCleanlooksStyle); dockwidget separators became visible.

Comment: Yes some styles have no frames and some do have. However if you do not set a style it will be the style set by the user (btw. thats always best!) so some users will not see frames. But it's their choice, somewhat.